# Redirecting localhost:3000/api/List to localhost:3001/api/List in VS Code Web Template Studio (React/Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, web-template-studio

When using the [Visual Studio Code's Web Template Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WebTemplateStudio) to create the boilerplate for a React app (localhost:3000) with a NodeJS API backend (localhost:3001), the React app makes calls to the API backend at, for example, `http://localhost:3000/api/List`, as seen in the Google Chrome browser's Network tab.

**Question:** When you go to `http://localhost:3000/api/List` using your browser, you see a webpage with headers and no content. To hit the API endpoint, we need to go to `http://localhost:3001/api/List`.

How does the code achieve this redirection from port 3000 to 3001? And why did they do this redirect instead of directly hitting port 3001?

Comment: Probably a reverse proxy rule, that tells that the route "api/List" on port 3000 has to be "understood" as localhost:3001/api/List

Comment: @Flo Your comment led me to https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development where I found the `proxy` property in `package.json` that is responsible for the redirect when using the development server. Is there a quick way to use this proxy rule when deployed in production?

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used React in production so I can't really help you on that point :/